# chrome.management.onInstalled and ExtensionInfo.enabled property

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have the following code in an extension which listens when extensions get Installed and Enabled :

```
chrome.management.onInstalled.addListener(function (e0) {
    console.log("installed", e0.name, "enabled=" + e0.enabled);
});
chrome.management.onEnabled.addListener(function (e2) {
    console.log("enabled", e2.name, "enabled=" + e2.enabled);
});
```

The onEnabled event gets fired always after the onInstalled event is fired, which makes sense. But the enabled property of the extension in the onInstalled event is always set to true. I think this is not right. This property should not be set to true until the onEnabled event is fired. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding something here ?

Thanks for any clue on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please understand [chrome.management.onEnabled.addListener()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#event-onEnabled) is an [**Event Listener**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#events) not a [**Method**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#methods).

Why do you want to look for an additional [Method\Overhead](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#methods) for enabling an extension\app, where [enabling](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-enable) and [disabling](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-disable) extensions is always possible after installation? Default value of [enabled to true](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#type-ExtensionInfo) is a good approach and please do not rely on execution flow because [event.addListener(function callback)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events.html#method-Event-addListener) is an asynchronous event.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer.
I am talking about the enabled property of the ExtensionInfo object passed to the callback function of the onInstalled event.

Comment: @RaphaelC: Yes i understood it :), but there is no `onEnabled() Method`, it is an event whose `invocation` we do not have control.

Comment: yes, but there is an "enabled" property on the "ExtensionInfo" object passed to the onInstalled callback function. That is the property I'm talking about. That property is set to "true" before the onEnabled event is triggered. And that seems wrong.

Comment: My bad, I think I understand what you mean when you say we don't have control on the invocation. You mean the onEnabled can get triggered any time after the enabled property has been set. But does it seem "normal" that the onInstalled event sends back an object with the enabled property set to true ?

Comment: @RaphaelC: `enabled` is set to `true` after installation by default (why do we expect users to install a disabled extension?) , but user can explicitly sets it to `false` if needed on case to case basis. More over [**addListener**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events.html#method-Event-addListener) event is an asynchronous event, please do not rely on execution flow

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Sudarshan, that really helps me get it clearer.  I understand that enabled is set to true by default on installation. I thought maybe the extension could be installed but disabled (for security reasons or whatever).

So, how would I go to check if an extension is installed and enabled ? I mean, is "enabled" finally just a flag ? Is onInstalled sufficient to say that the extension is installed and fully working or do I have to wait that onEnabled is fired ? If so, how do we know that an extension is installed and enabled ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `onInstalled()` event fires only once in its life time, but `onEnabled()` event fires any no of times(Ex: disable and enable cycles), `onInstalled()` notifies installation success and `onEnabled()` notifies active working status, enable flag in `onInstalled()` and `onEnabled()`events will always be **`true`**, so as a conclusion look for `onEnabled()` event for an extension installation and active status